# How can I center a placeholder text in a TextField

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

My code is as follow:

```
TextField("Enter Your Email", text: self.$username)
```

How can I make the placeholder "enter your email" be centered in the `TextField`?

Answer (score 24):

```
 TextField("Enter Your Email", text: self.$username)
        .multilineTextAlignment(TextAlignment.center)
```

Comment: This will center the text but it won't center the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code:

```
 yourtextfield.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: This is not SwiftUI

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on using the TextField placeholder. Instead I used `ZStack` to create my own view.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PlaceholderableTextField: View {

    @Binding var text: String
    let placeholder: String
    let axis: Axis

    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if text == "" && !isFocused {
                Text(placeholder).opacity(0.5)
            }

            TextField("", text: $text, axis: axis)
                .focused($isFocused)
        }
    }
}

struct PlaceholderableTextField_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PlaceholderableTextField(text: .constant("test"), placeholder: "placeholder", axis: .vertical)
    }
}
```

Then it's simple as

```swift
PlaceholderableTextField(text: $title, placeholder: "Enter Title", axis: .vertical)
    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```

Comment: You could accomplish the same by using
`.multilineTextAlignment((text.isEmpty && !isFocused)  ? .center : .leading)`

Answer (score -1):

```
let centeredParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
centeredParagraphStyle.alignment = .center
let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: centeredParagraphStyle])
textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
```

Answer (score -1):

```
              TextField("Enter Your Email", text: self.$username)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing) // .center|| .leading
```